# inline binding specification in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb, xjc

What is the inline option for something like this

xjc -d . -b bindings.xjb Derived.xsd

where my bindings.xsd will have

```
 <bindings scd="~tns:NameType">
      <class ref="com.bcbsmt.eie.pojo.commontypes.NameType"/>
 </bindings>
```

All i want to do is to prevent duplication of NameType everywhere.The requirement though is strictly internal binding.

I tried in Derived.xsd something like

```
<xs:element name="Name">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:class implClass="com.bcbsmt.eie.pojo.commontypes.NameType"></jaxb:class>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
```

But this didnt work out.Any ideas

Comment: Very interesting binding. What reference have you used to create it? AFAIK, you need [`<package>`](http://minitorn.tlu.ee/~jaagup/kool/java/abiinfo/javaeetutorial5/doc/JAXB9.html#wp103167)+[`<class>`](http://minitorn.tlu.ee/~jaagup/kool/java/abiinfo/javaeetutorial5/doc/JAXB9.html#wp103174) customizations.

Comment: Hey it just a  portion of my binding.I didnt generate the binding file.jaxb - xjc  did it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but below is an example of how the `jaxb:class` schema annotation can be used to point to an existing class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.1">

    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="bar"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="bar">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:class ref="example.BarImpl"></jaxb:class>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

If you want to reuse all the types generated from an XML schema, then you may find episode files useful:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html

Comment: i need to do what episode file does by inline annotation instruction.We now have episode which reuses the derived types.But we want to get rid of external episodes and used inline annotation to accomplish the same function.

Comment: @user1141359 - The XML schema I gave in my answer demonstrates what the inline schema annotation looks like.

Comment: Missed the trick subtle difference .I had <jaxb:class implClass="example.BarImpl"></jaxb:class> instead of <jaxb:class ref="example.BarImpl"></jaxb:class> .Didnt notice the first time in your answer .will try.thanks  a ton.